# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in draw3x3Grid for j in rang(3):

Tags: python

Hello I have an application GUI Sudoku Solver in python
I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yasen\Desktop\11.py", line 78, in 
draw9x9Grid()
File "C:\Users\yasen\Desktop\11.py", line 43, in draw9x9Grid
draw3x3Grid(rowNo,colNO,color)
File "C:\Users\yasen\Desktop\11.py", line 34, in draw3x3Grid
for j in rang(3):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Can you help me solve the problem or fix the code?
iget the code from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAXmfZmC2SI
Thanks

```
root: Tk=Tk()
root.title("Sudoku Silver")
root.geometry("1080x1080")

label=Label(root,text="Fill in number and click solve").grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=10)
errLabel=Label(root,text="",fg="red")
errLabel.grid(row=15,column=1,columnspan=10,pady=5)

solvedLabel=Label(root,text="",fg="blue")
solvedLabel.grid(row=15,column=1,columnspan=10,pady=5)

cells={}

def ValidateNumber(P):
    out=(P.isdigit()or P=="")and len(P)<2
    return out

reg = root.register(ValidateNumber)


def rang(param):
    pass


class Entery:
    pass


def draw3x3Grid(row, column, bgcolor):
    for i in range(3):
       for j in rang(3):
           e= Entery(root, width=5, bg=bgcolor,justify="center",validate="Key",validatecommand=(reg,"%P"))
           e.grid(row=row+i+1,column=column+j+1,sticky="nsew",padx=1,pady=1,ipady=5)
           cells[(row+i+1,column+j+1)]=e

def draw9x9Grid(colNO: object = None) -> object:
    color="#D0ffff"
    for rowNo in range(1,10,3):
        for colNo in range(0,9,3):
            draw3x3Grid(rowNo,colNO,color)

            if color=="#D0ffff":
                color="#ffffd0"
            else:
                color="#D0ffff"

def clearValues(solveLabel=None):
    errLabel.configure(text="")
    solveLabel.configure(text="")
    for row in range(2,11):
        for col in rang(1,10):
            cell=cells[(row,col)]
            cell.delete(0,"end")

def getValues(rwos=None):
    board=[]
    errLabel.configure(text="")
    solvedLabel.configure(text="")
    for row in rang(2,11):
        rows=[]
        for col in rang(1,10):
            val=cells[(row,col)].get()
            if val=="":
                rows.append(0)
            else:
                rwos.append(int(val))
        board.append(rows)
btn=Button(root,command=getValues,text="Solve",width=10)
btn.grid(row=20,column=1,columnspan=5,pady=20)

btn = Button(root, command=clearValues, text="Clear", width=10)
btn.grid(row=20, column=5, columnspan=5, pady=20)


draw9x9Grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `for j in rang(3):` Your `rang()` function does not return anything, therefore it returns None.

Comment: how can i fix it ?